# Hard drive gone missing after merging partition in an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery

After merging several partitions of an external hard drive using Magic Partition from Hiren's Boot (an old version). One of my drive is missing in the My Computer in window 8.1 (After I removed the external hard drive). I downloaded some free partition tools on the internet and found out that one of my partition is not assigned with a drive letter and the Paragon free Partition manager tells me that it is corrupted. What should I do to fix this? I have some important data in that partition and I want to get my data back. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've suffered the similar situation before. This question reminds me of MiniTool Partition Wizard, which has a sub-function called "Partition Recovery Wizard". You may use that function to scan your corrupted partition to see if that partition can be recovered. Anyway, like what above mentioned, you'd better avoid writing to the disk or partition as possible before you save out your data. If the partition can't fixed. You can also try to recover your data and back-up them, then repartition your external hard drive.